# Convert duplicate rows to separate columns in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
    ID      Date    Op  SS  type    
1   AR02    03-14   NA  SS  ET
2   AR02    03-14   NA  SS  ET  
3   AR02    06-14   NA  SS  ET  
4   AR03    31-14   NA  SS  ET  
5   AR08    03-14   NA  SS  ET  
6   AR09    03-14   NA  SS  EN
```

Since I have duplicate rows, I would like to get a table that appends all the duplicate rows as separate columns. Something like this.

```
    ID      Date    Op  SS  type ID     Date    Op  SS  type  ID    Date    Op  SS  type
1   AR02    03-14   NA  SS  ET   AR02   03-14   NA  SS  ET    AR02  06-14   NA  SS  ET  
2   AR03    31-14   NA  SS  ET   NA     NA      NA  NA  NA    NA    NA      NA  NA  NA  
3   AR08    03-14   NA  SS  ET   NA     NA      NA  NA  NA    NA    NA      NA  NA  NA  
4   AR09    03-14   NA  SS  EN   NA     NA      NA  NA  NA    NA    NA      NA  NA  NA
```

I am trying to do this in R. I tried melt, transpose (t), aggregate functions but somehow unable to get the right fix. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the desired transformation? If the *AR02* has 6 repeated dates would you like to create 6 columns: date_*n*, each for each repetition? Did you try `reshape(my.df,direction="wide", idvar = "ID", timevar = "Date")`?

Comment: I'm curious *why* you want your data in this wide format.

Comment: Thanks Konrad. Yes that was exactly what I was trying to get. Your suggestion was good but in this case I still found one of the duplicated rows (AR02) not appended to the rest.

Comment: @DMC: Just the way my experimental data is designed. This is a small example of the dataset I am working with. It includes 400+ samples and 33 columns. Just makes it convenient to look at all the samples in one row for further selection.

Comment: Yes Akrun. Thanks it was a great help. Have been breaking my head on this since this morning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`, grouped by 'ID', we `paste` the rows together, then use `cSplit` to split the pasted column ('V1') to separate columns.  Note that I am not repeating the 'ID' column as it is already unique for a row.

```
 library(splitstackshape)
 library(data.table)
 DT <- setDT(df1)[, do.call(paste, c(.SD, list(collapse=', '))) , ID]
 DT1 <- cSplit(DT, 'V1', sep='[ ,]+', fixed=FALSE, stripWhite=TRUE)
 setnames(DT1, 2:ncol(DT1), rep(names(df1)[-1], 3))
 DT1
 #     ID  Date Op SS type  Date Op SS type  Date Op SS type
 #1: AR02 03-14 NA SS   ET 03-14 NA SS   ET 06-14 NA SS   ET
 #2: AR03 31-14 NA SS   ET    NA NA NA   NA    NA NA NA   NA
 #3: AR08 03-14 NA SS   ET    NA NA NA   NA    NA NA NA   NA
 #4: AR09 03-14 NA SS   EN    NA NA NA   NA    NA NA NA   NA
```

It is not recommended to have duplicated column names, so

```
 setnames(DT1,  make.unique(names(DT1)))
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Akrun! Your fix was perfect! Much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Akrun, I have one question regarding your fix. Though the fix works perfectly, is there a way to retain the original headers for corresponding columns?

Comment: @Hash Updated the post, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Akrun. > setnames(DT1, 2:ncol(DT1), rep(names(df1)[-1], 3))                 I am still unable to get the original headers. I get V1_001, V1_002 and so on. Could you suggest a quick fix for this please? Also, I would like to retain the Id columns.  Can I just get rid of [-1] from rep(names(df1)[-1] to achieve that?

Comment: @Hash I am surprised about that as I couldn't reproduce the problem..  I am using `data.table_1.9.6`  Which version of data.table you are using?  The 'ID' column is retained.  Here I am just renaming all the other columns except the ID using `setnames`

Comment: Akrun, it was my bad. I am sorry. I was using the code as it is on a different dataset. Found the mistake I was making. Thanks anyway for all your help.

Comment: @Hash I am at workplace.  The link is blocked as well as email accounts.

Comment: No problem Akrun. When it is convenient please have a look at it if possible. Thanks