# Creating a function to fetch europmc literature to skip paper which does't return tables

Tags: r, function

This was my question which I would like to follow up. [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65952017/parsing-of-pmcid-table-row-to-column-form/65963071#65963071)

I m following a rather complex way to do what I want to do as of now.

But a simple solution which proposed by [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3460670/ben) was this

```
library(tidypmc)
library(tidyverse)
library(europepmc)

doc <- map("PMC7809753", epmc_ftxt)
tbls <- pmc_table(doc[[1]])
tbls[[1]]
```

My objective was i was trying to do. See **drugs or disease etc on europmc which have open access** and the fetch its data `**as a tabular form`** and save it.

To achieve the first part this does the job

```
library(europepmc)
b <-epmc_search(query = 'cytarabine aml OPEN_ACCESS:Y',limit = 20)
pmcids <- b$pmcid[b$isOpenAccess=="Y"]
```

I get pmcids which class is character.

To do the second part as [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3460670/ben) suggested this works really well.

```
doc <- map("PMC7809753", epmc_ftxt)
tbls <- pmc_table(doc[[1]])
tbls[[1]]
```

To address the above with help a generous stackoverflow user I got this function

```
b <-epmc_search(query = 'cytarabine aml OPEN_ACCESS:Y',limit = 6)
pmcids <- b$pmcid[b$isOpenAccess=="Y"]
    pub_tables <- lapply(pmcids, function(pmc_id) {
      message("-- Trying ", pmc_id, "...")
      doc <- tryCatch(pmc_xml(pmc_id), 
                      error = function(e) {
                        message("------ Failed to recover PMCID")
                        return(NULL)
                      })
      if(!is.null(doc)) { 
        #-- If succeed, try to get table
        tables <- pmc_table(doc)
        if(!is.null(tables)) {
          #-- If succeed, try to get table name
          table_caps <- pmc_caption(doc) %>%
            filter(tag == "table")
          names(tables) <- paste(table_caps$label, table_caps$text, sep = " - ")
        }
        return(tables) 
      } else {
        #-- If fail, return NA
        return(NA)
      }
    })
    names(pub_tables) <- pmcids
```

This works well but i got this error

```
Error in names(tables) <- paste(table_caps$label, table_caps$text, sep = " - ") : 
  'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [2]
```

These are my pmcids which Im using to query it with limit set to 6.

```
"PMC7837979" "PMC7809753" "PMC7790830" "PMC7797573" "PMC7806552" "PMC7836575"
```

Now how do i skip those papers where if I dont get any information then I will skip to the next one in other words how to work around this error.

I have very tiny/minute experience in creating complicated function but from the code if i understand this chunk of code should be working on it but not sure why it is not!!.

```
} else {
    #-- If fail, return NA
    return(NA)
  }


Error in names(tables) <- paste(table_caps$label, table_caps$text, sep = " - ") : 
      'names' attribute [3] must be the same length as the vector [2]
```

For example When the limit is set 4 it works well the pub_tables is returned as list and the last pmcid is returned as

```
$PMC7797573
NULL
```

But the problem occurs with `"PMC7806552"`. So how do i get the null result when i see an error in fetching table and then move to the next PMCIDs.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Or there is any simpler way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the function modified slightly to work.  The only edit is that I added these lines:

```
table_caps <- table_caps %>% group_by(label) %>% 
   summarise(text = paste(text, collapse=" "), 
             tag = "table")
```

after the initial definition of the `table_caps` object.  The problem was that some table captions had multiple sentences.  This pastes the multiple sentences together.

```
b <-epmc_search(query = 'cytarabine aml OPEN_ACCESS:Y',limit = 10)
pmcids <- b$pmcid[b$isOpenAccess=="Y"]
pub_tables <- lapply(pmcids, function(pmc_id) {
  message("-- Trying ", pmc_id, "...")
  doc <- tryCatch(pmc_xml(pmc_id), 
                  error = function(e) {
                    message("------ Failed to recover PMCID")
                    return(NULL)
                  })
  if(!is.null(doc)) { 
    #-- If succeed, try to get table
    tables <- pmc_table(doc)
    if(!is.null(tables)) {
      #-- If succeed, try to get table name
      table_caps <- pmc_caption(doc) %>%
        filter(tag == "table")
      table_caps <- table_caps %>% group_by(label) %>% 
        summarise(text = paste(text, collapse=" "), 
                  tag = "table")
      names(tables) <- paste(table_caps$label, table_caps$text, sep = " - ")
    }
    return(tables) 
  } else {
    #-- If fail, return NA
    return(NA)
  }
})
```

Comment: let me run it and will come back to u.................

Comment: Sir you saved couple of hours  of my PhD for sure. thanks for the generous help. I think its time for me to really learn how to create functions.

Comment: when I communicate the paper I will surely cite and acknowledge these answers.